# How to add a method on ngOnDestroy in angular decorator without overriding the original ngOnDestroy method?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to add a method on ngOnDestroy in angular decorator without overriding the original ngOnDestroy method?
I have already tried to add a ngOnDestroy on my code in decorator but it overrides the classes ngOnDestroy.

````
    constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
        for (let i in this) {
            if (typeof this[i].unsubscribe !== 'undefined') {
                this[i].unsubscribe();
                console.log("unsubscribed!!");
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: When you implement the ngOnDestroy method in component, its not overriden

Comment: Implement OnDestroy and add ngOnDestroy on the component class, it won't override it won't override it but tell angular how to dispose of the component

Comment: Check this [Netatel Basal's link](https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88): get the "original" and apply after your code

Comment: Also, you can just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/until-destroy

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the original implementation to a variable and call it inside of your implementaion.

```
function unsubscribeAll(constructor: Function) {
     const onDestroy = constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy ?? () => {};
     constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
        onDestroy.call(this);
        for (let i in this) {
            if (typeof this[i].unsubscribe !== 'undefined') {
                this[i].unsubscribe();
                console.log("unsubscribed!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for giving your valueable answer.